# What is max file upload size in IIS6.0? and how do we overcome that?

Tags: asp.net, iis

In my application, I would like to upload files of size more than 3GB.  I increased max file request timeout as high as possible.

But it is not even posting the page to the server when I select a 3GB file.

My web site configuration:

1. Asp.Net 3.5
2. IIS 6.0

Is it possible with the above configuration? If not what is the reason, and how do I resolve this?

Comment: Ramesh, can you provide some more info on the system? What are the file types, why are they so large, what environment are you working in (i.e. network speed and quality), etc. The more info the better.

Comment: The filetypes are flv,avi.
Our customers will upload board meetings videos for the year or two year or etc..

They will upload those bigsize videos.
My network speed is 500kbps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably go with a FTP approach. Using FTPWebRequest - try Google for sample code.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to adjust both the timeout and request length in your web.config appropriately:

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime  maxRequestLength="102400" executionTimeout="360"/>
</system.web>
```

Of course keep in mind, a 3Gb file is going to require a lot of patience. In reality, I suggest investigating alternatives - HTTP post is not going to be pretty with files of this size.

Comment: So what is the max upload filesize?

Comment: You'll eventually reach resource limits on the server as you upload larger files - you can't go on indefinitely increasing file size. The maximum you'll get away with will be dependent on the configuration of your server environment. The configuration process is the same for IIS6 & 7. BTW - see Robert Harvey's response for a suitable alternative.

Comment: Can we use FTP upload if it exceeds more than 1GB?

What do you think Troy?

Comment: Yes, you can use FTP. With files of this size though you should be considering your network connectivity (speed and quality), how long it will realistically take to upload a file and what mitigation you have for connection dropouts if the duration is significant.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility: http://www.banmanpro.com/support2/File_Upload_limits.asp

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately adjusting the timeout and request length is not going to work.  Your web server will run out of memory before the upload completes.

What you need is a file upload control that will break your upload into smaller chunks, so that you don't use all of the server's memory to hold the file while it is uploading.

One of the better file upload controls available is **[Darren Johnstone's ASP.NET File Upload control.](http://darrenjohnstone.net/aspnet-file-uploaddownload-module-v2-documentation/)**  This free control is a drop-in replacement for the standard ASP.NET file upload component, and is specifically designed to handle large files.  It even includes a progress bar that doesn't require Flash.

*Complete documentation and installation instructions are here*:
http://darrenjohnstone.net/aspnet-file-uploaddownload-module-v2-documentation/

*The control (and source code) can be downloaded here*:
http://darrenjohnstone.net/downloads/

Comment: Execellent Robert,  

But i have some doubts regarding this.

1.I need to upload .flv files.How do make that files as small chunks? 
2.Is there any software which can break my fileinto smaller ones or by the control itself will it do?

Comment: I have downloaded and used the above control , still its not accepting 2GB file.

Comment: it simple says wait in progress bar.

Comment: Did you follow all the instructions for installation?  The control requires that you hookup an Http Handler so that the file chunking can take place.  I have used this control in an ASP.NET project I am working on, and it works beautifully.  Try the sample project provided with the control first.